# Is header of ListView considered item?

Tags: android, header, android-listview, position

Why adding header to `listView` moves items position by one?

When I add header, position of first item in the list is no longer 0 but 1. Why?

Comment: It seems that yes. Anyway I don't use built-in headers and footers and I prefer to apply a custom xml layout to the list view activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'header' is representing the same data as all other items, but has different layout.

The header might contain data and it might not. (you might not be using it but another developer could easily add list data to his header and footer).

Thus since the header could contain data it is in fact an item, which occupies position 0. Similarly footer occupies the last position (if used)